# Number of permutations of thet set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ in which $k$ is never followed immediately by $k+1$

Tags: combinatorics

For $n \in \mathbb N$, let $C_n$ denote the number of permutations of the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ in which k is never followed immediately by $k+1$ for each $k=1,2,...,n-1$

i) Find $C_n$

ii) Show that $C_n = D_n + D_{n-1}$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$

I know that the number of r-combinations of a set which contains no consecutive integers is given by $\binom{n-r+1}{r}$ but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Answer given for

(i) $C_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{i}\binom{n-1}{i}(n-i)!$

Comment: I am just wondering but what does $D_n$ represent?

Comment: $D_n$ is the number of permutations of $\mathbb N_n$ that has no fixed points.

Comment: In other words, $D_n$ is the number of derangements of $\mathbb N_n$

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

1) Let $A_i$ be the set of permutations where $i$ is followed by $i+1$ for $1\le i\le n-1$, and then use the
 Inclusion-Exclusion formula to find $\left|A_1^{c}\cap\cdots\cap A_{n-1}^{c}\right|$.

2) Use that $\displaystyle(-1)^{i}\binom{n-1}{i}(n-i)!=(-1)^{i}\frac{(n-1)!}{i!}(n-i)=\left[(-1)^{i}\frac{n}{i!}-(-1)^{i-1}\frac{1}{(i-1)!}\right](n-1)!$

along with the formula for $D_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. For the first part, apply the inclusion-exclusion formula. Note that the number of permutations such that $k + 1$ follows $k$ for each $k = k_1, k_2, \dots k_i$ is $(n-i)!$ irrespective of how the numbers $k_1, \dots, k_i$ are situated.

Comment: By inclusion-exclusion formula, you are referring to this right? $$E(m)=\sum_{k=m}^{q}(-1)^{k-m}\binom{k}{m}\omega(k)$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with those notations. I'm talking about this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inclusion-ExclusionPrinciple.html Take $A_k$ to be the set of permutations in which $k$ is immediately followed by $k+1$.