# Number of sequences of length $m$ such that $1$ is never followed immediately by $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, generating-functions

> Find the number of sequences of length $m$ consisting of only digits, where each digit is in $\{0,1,2\}$ and such that $1$ is never followed immediately by $0$.

Attempt: I tried taking 10 as a block, but I got nowhere. I found the *Mathematics* question *[Number of permutations of thet set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ in which $k$ is never followed immediately by $k+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952006)*.

Using that, since I need to remove only 1 followed by 0, I get only one set $A_1$ so, $3^m$ - 6 (3*2). Pick the other number in three ways, and we can permute 10 and other number in two ways). Is this right?
I am from a non-math background; kindly consider this if possible.

Comment: It is assumed that the three digits are equi-probable to occur, right?

Comment: @GCab: **Number of sequences** has nothing to do with probability.

Comment: @user21820, well, yes you are right "definition-wise", we are talking of $m$-ary words from alphabet ${0,1,2}$. However $N/N_{tot}$ is bi-jective with the " probability of the sequence of $m$ equi-probable events, ...", isn't it?

Comment: One big problem with a probability-based approach is that the obvious events are not independent. e.g. assuming all entries are chosen uniformly randomly, if X is the event that the first two entries are `10` and Y is the event that the second two entries are `10`, then $P(X) = 1/9$ but $P(X|Y) = 0$.

Comment: @user21820: Number of sequences is $3^m$ times the probability that a uniformly randomly selected sequence of length $m$ is of the type we want.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Of course I know that. I was responding to *G Cab*'s irrelevant comment.

Comment: @GCab: You don't know what you're talking about. Whatever you mean by $N / N_{tot}$ is probably a **number**, and it is meaningless to say that a number is in bijection with anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT: Call such sequence *good*, and let $a_n$ be the number of good sequences of length $n$. If $\sigma$ is a good sequence of length $n$, we can form $3a_n$ sequences of length $n+1$ by appending a $0,1$, or $2$ to the end of $\sigma$. Every good sequence of length $n+1$ can be obtained in this way, but unfortunately so can some bad ones. The bad ones are those that end in $10$. These are clearly obtained by appending $01$ to a good sequence of length $n-1$, and there are $a_{n-1}$ of those, so our count of $3a_n$ includes exactly $a_{n-1}$ bad sequences, and we find that $a_{n+1}=3a_n-a_{n-1}$, or

$$a_n=3a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\tag{1}$$

with initial values $a_0=1$ (because the empty sequence is good) and $a_1=3$.

Now use your favorite method to solve the recurrence $(1)$ to get a closed form for $a_n$.

**A Shortcut:** If you calculate the first few $a_n$, you get the following table:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&0&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
a_n:&1&3&8&21&55&144&377
\end{array}$$

If you recognize the bottom row as a subsequence of some familiar sequence, you may be able to prove that it really *is* that subsequence and use that to get a closed form more easily.

**Added:** Since **Jack D’Aurizio** has now mentioned the Fibonacci numbers explicitly, I’ll elaborate on the shortcut bit. It’s quite well known (and easy to show) that the number of ways to tile a $1\times n$ strip using $1\times 1$ and $1\times 2$ tiles (monominoes and dominoes) is $F_{n+1}$. Thus, there are $F_{2n+2}$ ways to tile a strip of length $2n+1$. Number the cells of the strip $1$ through $2n+1$ from left to right, and suppose that we have a tiling of the strip by monominoes and dominoes. Label each even-numbered cell $L$ if it’s covered by the left half of a domino, $R$ if it’s covered by the right half of a domino, and $S$ if it’s covered by a monomino. There are $n$ even-numbered cells, so this labelling produces a string of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{L,R,S\}$. The only restriction on these strings is that they cannot contain the substring $LR$ (why?). Thus, there are $F_{2n+2}$ strings of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{L,R,S\}$ in which $L$ is never followed by $R$. Replace $L,R$, and $S$ by $1,0$, and $2$, respectively, to map these strings to the ones in the problem.

Comment: Nice job (+1) as always, but a natural question arises: is there some way to directly show that the answer is given by a Fibonacci number, for instance by showing a bijection between the valid strings and the tilings of a strip by $1\times 1$ and $2\times 1$ tiles?

Comment: @Jack: Thanks. Yes, I just thought of one. Take a strip of length $2n+1$ and number the cells from $1$ through $2n+1$. Tile with monominoes and dominoes. Assign a code to each even-numbered cell: L if it’s covered by the left half of a domino, R if it’s covered by the right half of a domino, and S if it’s covered by a monomino. The only forbidden sequence is LR. (I’m off to the grocery store, but I may this to the answer later; it’s kind of cute.)

Comment: I've found an equivalent formulation :D

Answer (score 7):

We may consider a Markov chain with three states $\{0,1,2\}$, corresponding to the last parsed character. The adjacency matrix of such a Markov chain is
$$ P=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$
(so just the transition $0\mapsto 1$ is not allowed) and the number $S_m$ of strings of $m\geq 1$ characters with the given property is the sum of the elements of $P^{m-1}$. You may now compute $S_m$ from a spectral decomposition of $P$. The usual combinatorial way is to consider that any valid string with length $m$ may only start with a prefix among
$$ 1,\quad 2,\quad 02,\quad 002,\quad 0002,\quad \ldots,\quad 000\ldots000.$$
It follows that, by setting $S_0=1$,
$$ S_m = 2 S_{m-1} + S_{m-2} + S_{m-3} + \ldots + S_{0} $$
$$ S_{m+1} = 2 S_{m} + S_{m-1} + S_{m-2} + \ldots + S_{0} $$
$$ S_{m+1}-S_{m} = 2S_m-2S_{m-1}+S_{m-1} $$
and
$$ S_{m+1} = 3S_{m}-S_{m-1},\quad S_0=1, S_1=3 $$
so
$$\boxed{ S_m = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n+1}\right]=\color{red}{F_{2n+2}} }$$
the number of our strings is given by a Fibonacci number. A combinatorial bijection showing the same can be the following one: if we map $0\mapsto 01$, $1\mapsto 10$, $2\mapsto 00$, the valid strings having length $n$ are mapped into the binary strings of length $2n$ with the property that two "$1$s" are never next to each other. For instance:
$$ 021002 \mapsto 010010010100 $$
and the latter problem is a famous problem.

Answer (score 2):

For variety, let $A_n$ be the number of such sequences of length $n$ that end in a $1$.

Let $B_n$ be the number of such sequences of length $n$ that do not end in a $1$.

Then,

- $A_0 = 0$
- $B_0 = 1$
- $A_{n+1} = A_n + B_n$
- $B_{n+1} = A_n + 2 B_n$

You can use your favorite method to solve this recurrence relation.

(phrases for further searching: "linear recurrence", "difference equation")

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based upon the *[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)*.

> We consider the set words of length $m\geq 0$ built from an alphabet $$\mathcal{V}=\{0,1,2\}$$ and the set $B=\{10\}$ of *bad words*, which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for. We derive a generating function $f(s)$ with the coefficient of $s^m$ being  the number of searched words of length $m$.

According to the paper (p.7) the generating function $f(s)$  is
\begin{align*}
f(s)=\frac{1}{1-ds-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=3$, the size of the alphabet and $\mathcal{C}$ the *weight-numerator* of bad words with
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[10])
\end{align*}
We calculate according to the paper
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[10])&=-s^2\\
\end{align*}

and get

> \begin{align*}
> f(s)&=\frac{1}{1-ds-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-3s+s^2}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> Partial fraction decomposition and expansion of $f(s)$ results in
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(s)&=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}}s}
> -\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}}s}\\
> &\\
> &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left[\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{m+1}-\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{m+1}\right]s^m\\
> \\
> &=1+3s+8s^2+21s^3+\color{blue}{55}s^4+144s^5+377s^6+\cdots
> \end{align*}
>   with the coefficient of $s^m$ giving the number of valid words of length $m$.

The number  of valid words of  length $4$ is $55$. Here is a list showing all $4^3=81$ words and the $26$ invalid words marked with blue.

\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0000&0\color{blue}{10}0&0200&\color{blue}{10}00&1\color{blue}{10}0&1200&2000&2\color{blue}{10}0&2200\\
0001&0\color{blue}{10}1&0201&\color{blue}{10}01&1\color{blue}{10}1&1201&2001&2\color{blue}{10}1&2201\\
0002&0\color{blue}{10}2&0202&\color{blue}{10}02&1\color{blue}{10}2&1202&2002&2\color{blue}{10}2&2202\\
00\color{blue}{10}&01\color{blue}{10}&02\color{blue}{10}&\color{blue}{10}\color{blue}{10}&11\color{blue}{10}&12\color{blue}{10}&20\color{blue}{10}&21\color{blue}{10}&22\color{blue}{10}\\
0011&0111&0211&\color{blue}{10}11&1111&1211&2011&2111&2211\\
0012&0112&0212&\color{blue}{10}12&1112&1212&2012&2112&2212\\
0020&0120&0220&\color{blue}{10}20&1120&1220&2020&2120&2220\\
0021&0121&0221&\color{blue}{10}21&1121&1221&2021&2121&2221\\
0022&0122&0222&\color{blue}{10}22&1122&1222&2022&2122&2222\\
\end{array}